# How to use librdkafka to change retention time for the running kafka topic

Tags: c++, apache-kafka

We can use the following command in kafka machine to update the retention time for the running kafka topic:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <kafka_ip> --alter --topic <target_topic> --config retention.ms=86400000
```

But I don't want to login to the kafka machine and run the command.
I just want to use C or C++ to change kafka retention time for the running kafka topic in the remote producer machine.

Question is: Can we use api in librdkafka to update the retention time for the running kafka topic?

note: Now we can produce and consume kafka data with C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rd_kafka_AlterConfigs()` and pass it a TOPIC resource with all current topic configuration as well as your updated configuration `retention.ms`.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/librdkafka/rdkafka_8h.html#ade8d161dfb86a94179d286f36ec5b28e

Answer (score 0):

Is there also a way to map this using the c ++ API?
Until the topic configuration is set by RdKafka::Topic::create, why the conf object doesn't support 'retention.ms', as I found here https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#retention.ms 'retention.ms' is a topic configuration.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)